# Gorilla sessions not working on Google compute (using Docker)

Tags: docker, go, session, google-compute-engine, gorilla

Go Gorilla sessions is not working on Google compute (using Docker), but it works perfectly fine when running it locally.

I am using this

```
cfg := config.Get()
log.Printf("Getting session from SessionStore ")
session, err := s.sessionStore.Get(r, cfg.SessionKey)
log.Printf("MY_SESSION: ", session)
```

I am getting this weird message in the logs

```
admin_1           | [00] 2020/04/09 20:20:50 Getting session from SessionStore
admin_1           | [00] 2020/04/09 20:20:50 MY_SESSION: %!(EXTRA *sessions.Session=&{ map[] 0xc000250c40 true 0xc00064c040 _m_said})
```

When I run it locally, it works fine with the following in the logs:

```
admin_1           | [00] 2020/04/09 20:06:00 Getting session from SessionStore
admin_1           | [00] 2020/04/09 20:06:00 MY_SESSION: %!(EXTRA *sessions.Session=&{T5ATM7BPRJIHPCTA4MQQWZ7MMFE75EWPSTM732PH2ME52NSMIUIA map[admin_id:c010315d-c1ff-44b2-abb4-0d7b328fe404] 0xc000424e80 false 0xc000300100 _m_said})
```

When running locally, I have `localhost` as the SESSION_DOMAIN, when running the docker image on Google compute engine I have updated the SESSION_DOMAIN to the `external ip` and I also tried using a real domain that I registered in Google domains and tying it to the Google Compute engine VM IP, I am getting the same errors.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: I am getting this error *sessions.Session=&{ map[] 0xc000250c40 true 0xc00064c040 _m_said} . Expected result is EXTRA *sessions.Session=&{T5ATM7BPRJIHPCTA4MQQWZ7MMFE75EWPSTM732PH2ME52NSMIUIA map[admin_id:c010315d-c1ff-44b2-abb4-0d7b328fe404] 0xc000562940 false 0xc000300100 _m_said} . Its like something is being rejected.

Comment: SESSION_DOMAIN is just related because of the cookies. When Googling and reading the docs, it was stated that cookies could get rejected or blocked if the domain doesn't match when dealing with session data.

Comment: With my testing, I created a login page, the creates the session, logs/verifies. So in the end, when running the app with docker locally, I am able to login fine, but when I move the code to a server, I can login at all.

Comment: @teej2542 Very likely. The code snippet you showed tells pretty much nothing. Please add a [mcve]. Furthermore, you might want to have a deeeep look into [http.Cookie](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Cookie). As a side note: it is a Very Bad Idea™ to implement security related code without knowing _exactly_ what you are doing.

Comment: It was a domain issue. It is working now.

Comment: "I am getting this error *sessions.Session..." -- That is not an error. That is your debug output, generated by `log.Printf("MY_SESSION", session)`